# Finding corners of box and crop Image

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, object-detection

Hey Guys I am working with numpy and opencv and want to get a image cropped by the contours of it. Here is one example what picture i want to crop by the edges,
[image]

And i want that the yellow line (rectangle) get cropped by python,

[image]

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2
from PIL import Image


image = cv2.imread('4.png')
result = image.copy()
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lower = np.array([103, 131, 70])
upper = np.array([179, 234, 255])
mask = cv2.inRange(image, lower, upper)
result = cv2.bitwise_and(result, result, mask=mask)


print(image.shape)
cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can opt for the LAB color space.

***Now why use LAB color space over HSV?***

- It's easier to segment the color of your choice by analyzing the chroma channels.
- There is no need to manually fix a range (unlike in HSV color space). Otsu threshold will help.

***What is LAB color space?***

- *L-channel* : represents **brightness** value in the image
- *A-channel* : represents variation of color between **red** and **green**
- *B-channel* : represents variation of color between **blue** and **yellow**

[Visit this page for better visualization](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/The-CIELAB-color-space-diagram-The-CIELAB-or-CIE-L-a-b-color-system-represents_fig1_338303610)

After analyzing the a-channel and b-channel for the LAB converted image, we will make use of the a-channel since the box can be segmented easily here.

```
img = cv2.imread('image_path')
lab = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
a_component = lab[:,:,1]
```

[image]

```
th = cv2.threshold(a_component,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(th, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
c = max(contours, key = cv2.contourArea)

black = np.zeros((img.shape[0], img.shape[1]), np.uint8)
mask = cv2.drawContours(black,[c],0,255, -1)
```

[image]

```
result = cv2.bitwise_and(result, result, mask=mask)
```

[image]

Hope this is the result you were expecting

Comment: Nice use of LAB color space. But one could also just threshold on red using cv2.inRange().

Comment: @fmw42 Thank you. Red is a common color so the range is available easily. But when it comes to some other color we need to manually find the range and then threshold. However, using A or B channels of LAB color space you can avoid finding range manually.

Comment: Good point about having to find the red range manually!

Comment: Yeah it worked out really good thank you mate :) i have got one question left, can you tell me how crop it automatically by the mask? so that ein got a picture only from the box? Thanke you