# How to crop and extract stamp from an image with OpenCV?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am new to OpenCV.
I have a "simple" image of a stamp that I have already processed a bit, as you can see in the code below.
Now I have the problem of cropping the image to get just the stamp.
The dots and the stripes on the edges interfere with my current code recognizing the stamp.
The images can be different so it is not an option to fix the location of the image.

Code:

```
img = cv2.imread('./images/image.JPG')
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img_gray, (3,3), 0) 
edges = cv2.Canny(image=img_blur, threshold1=100, threshold2=200)
```

[image: First Example Image]

[image: Second Example Image]

Real Images
[image: First Real Example Image]

[image: Second Real Example Image]

Comment: Post your original images. There may be a better way than to use Canny edge processing.

Comment: you could try segmenting based on color space https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72014761/finding-corners-of-box-and-crop-image/72015294#72015294 , Its always my go-to technique

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simple method:

1. **Obtain binary image.** We load the image, convert to grayscale, Gaussian blur, then Otsu's threshold to obtain a binary image.
2. **Remove small artifacts and noise.** Create a rectangular structuring element and morph open to remove small bits of noise. Then morph close to combine individual contours into a single contour with the assumption that a stamp is a single contour.
3. **Detect and extract stamp ROI.** Find contours, filter using contour area and shape approximation. The idea is that if a contour has four vertices then it's a square shape. We can extract the stamp ROI using Numpy slicing and save the stamp

---

Extracted ROI results

[image]
[image]

Here's the results with the other two input images from the comments. The assumption is that for each image, there's only one stamp, or one group of adjacent stamps. For these cases, we sort by contour area and assume the largest contour is the stamp.

[image]

[image]

Code

```
import cv2

# Load image, grayscale, Gaussian blur, Otsu's threshold
image = cv2.imread("1.jpg")
original = image.copy()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5,5), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Morph operations to remove small artifacts and noise
open_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3,3))
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, open_kernel, iterations=1)
close_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (7,7))
close = cv2.morphologyEx(opening, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, close_kernel, iterations=2)

# Find contours, filter using contour area, and shape approximation
cnts = cv2.findContours(close, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
cnts = sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)
for c in cnts:
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.05 * peri, True)
    # Assumption is if the contour has 4 vertices then its a square shape
    # 2nd assumption is that there's only one stamp, or one group of stamps
    if len(approx) == 4 and area > 100:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(approx)
        ROI = original[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        cv2.imshow("ROI", ROI)
        cv2.imwrite("ROI.png", ROI)
        break
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort you made to answer. However, I forgot to add that I also have images like this document (https://imgur.com/a/C7cORLy) or this group of stamps (the group should be merged as one). It does not work for these 2 cases, otherwise, it works perfectly!

Comment: If you want the group of stamps to be merged as one entity, you will need to perform some different morphological operations and then proceed. This answer should be perfect for you since only contours with 4 vertices are captured. You might want to adjust the area threshold as well.

Comment: @DJCool check the update, it should work with your other cases now. The assumption is that for each image, there's one single stamp or one group of adjacent stamps to extract.

Comment: Thank you very much @nathancy. I tried it and it works very well, but for some sets, it doesn't work properly (https://imgur.com/a/LL73B7I).  It only cuts off the first line, or if there are only 2, it only takes one of the two. I don't understand why this is happening. Do you have any idea?

Comment: It's pretty much impossible to get a solution for all those variations using simple image processing. One thing you could do is preprocess the image input images so there's no large "white border" section since those will be used in the contour area checks. It's probably because those areas are larger than the stamp contours so its cropping those instead. You can add additional checks to handle those situations. Another thing you could do is increase the close kernel size `(7,7)` and the number of iterations. For a proper solution, you may have to train your own model with machine learning

Comment: Thank you very much! I agree with the point that machine learning would be a proper solution. However, increasing the kernel size (7, 7) to (40, 40) fixed the problem and now all images are cropped as they should be!