# Is there feasible way to delete picture except detected object?

Tags: python, opencv, yolov5

i want to detect a specific object with Yolov5 but i want to delete rest of picture except cardboard boxes. I have a code that measuring objects with opencv but it measuring everything. I want to detect only cardboard boxes. Should i delete rest of picture or is there any feasible solution for this?

[image: measuring everything]

Comment: Refer to this answer by [nathancy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11162165/nathancy) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72020710/crop-and-extract-stamp-from-an-image. Here you can filter contours that are box shaped (with 4 vertices) and proceed further

Comment: @JeruLuke thank i will check this.