# How can I delete the background outside the drawn contours?

Tags: python, opencv, pytorch, computer-vision, yolo

How can I delete the background outside the drawn contours?
My main goal is measure size of ONLY cardboard boxes.
I have 2 differend code.

First code measuring EVERYTHING with aruco marker.

Second code is detecting boxes with yolo.(I need this because measure code detects everything)

Both of them drawn contours.

My measure code is measuring everything thats why i want to remove background except contoured objects.

how can i manage this?

Please help.

[image]

Comment: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72039541/is-there-feasible-way-to-delete-picture-except-detected-object

Answer (score 2):

Create black mask image. For each detection draw it contour on mask:

```
cv2.drawContours(img, contours, -1, color=(255, 255, 255), thickness=cv2.FILLED)
```

And after make bitwise_and with this mask.

Comment: İ understood but yolo have plot_one_box(torch) code instead of cv2.drawcontour. is this a problem?

Comment: No, You can apply mask before plot_one_box

Comment: i have a problem with yolo, can you help my new question?

Answer (score 0):

[GrabCut](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/d83/tutorial_py_grabcut.html) algorithm seems like what you need in this case. It will distinguish background and foreground pixels inside a bounding box.